# Jquery Validator rules not updating when resubmitting erroneous form

Tags: jquery, submit, validation, validationrules

I have a form with two interdependent fields, one a set of two radio buttons, the other a text field.

When the radio button has one value selected, the text field should be required. When the other field is selected, it is not required. Fairly simple in concept.

This has been implemented through a function like the following, called upon form submission:

```
function validateForm(form, incremental) {
    ...
    validator = $(form).validate({
        ...
        rules:{
            "textfield-name":{
            required: $("input:radio[name=auth]:checked").val() == 'A'
        },
        ...
    });
    return validator.form();
```

So, this works very well the first time the form is submitted. If the radio to allow an empty input is checked, the form submits ok. If the other button is checked, the form page shows the empty text field highlighted as an error.

However, after submitting an erroneous form where the text field was empty and the radio button mandating a value was checked, if I go ahead and leave the text field blank but change the radio button to allow a blank field, the form still does not submit, and the text field is still highlighted in error.

When I step through the javascript using Firebug debugger, I can see that it does restep through the validate() function that ostensibly is creating a new validator, and I can see the expression for the "required" rule for the field is evaluating to false on the second submit, as expected. Yet, once the validate code is stepped through, I look at the resultant validator object's rule set within it's settings, and they remain unchanged. Is the Validator for a form locked once it's instantiated somehow, or is there any way to successfully update it's rule set between validation runs?

Comment: Figures after fighting all day on this I'd come up with the solution 10 minutes after posting here :) .
Setting the required rule to a function that returned the boolean instead of the boolean expression itself seems to fix it.

    ...
    rules:{
        "textfield-name":{
        required: function() {
            return $("input:radio[name=auth]:checked").val() == 'A';
        }
    },
    ...